# How to transform a written sequence into a numeric sequence? (R)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm in trouble with a dataset provided by the Brazilian government (therefore, it is in portuguese). Here's the code that imports it:

```
library(tidyverse)
locais_vot_SP <- read_delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camilagonc/votacao_secao/master/locais_vot_SP.csv",
                        locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
                        delim = ",",
                        col_names = F) %>% 
              filter(X4 == "VINHEDO")

names(locais_vot_SP) <- c("num_zona", 
                      "nome_local",
                      "endereco",
                      "nome_municipio",
                      "secoes",
                      "secoes_esp")
```

As it can be noticed, the values of the variable `secoes` are not properly organized, since different data are aggregated in the same cell.

```
secoes
196ª; 207ª; 221ª; 231ª;
197ª; 211ª; 230ª; 249ª;
```

With the following code, I started to fix the problem:

```
locais_vot_SP <- locais_vot_SP %>% mutate(secoes = gsub("ª", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub("ª", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub(";", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub("Da ", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   separate_rows(secoes, sep = ";") %>%  
                                   mutate(secoes = unlist(strsplit(locais_vot_SP$secoes, ";")))
```

And so I got to this:

```
secoes
32 à 38
100
121
```

What still needs to be solved are the cases in which there is `x à y` (in English, `x to y`). How can I get the following output?

```
secoes
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep your basic workflow but used `gsubfn` to apply a function to the regular expression that was used to extract the two numbers that needed to be extrapolated.

```
library(gsubfn)
locais_vot_SP <- locais_vot_SP %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes = unlist(strsplit(gsubfn("(\\d+)ª à (\\d+)", function(x,y) paste0(seq(x,y),collapse = "ª;"),secoes),","))) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub("ª", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub("ª", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes_esp = gsub(";", "", secoes_esp)) %>%
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub("Da ", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub(" ", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   mutate(secoes = gsub(";$", "", secoes)) %>% 
                                   separate_rows(secoes, sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

by creating a range you will change the length of the column. Sicne you seem to only care about that column it's easiest do this

```
map(
    locais_vot_SP$secoes,
    ~seq(
      as.numeric(str_extract(., "^(\\d+)")),
      as.numeric(str_extract(., "(\\d+)$")))) %>% 
  reduce(c)
```

or continue your pipeline by doing `%>% pull(secoes) %>% map(...) %>% reduce(c) %>% data.frame(secoes = .)` If you need it in a 1-column dataframe.

If there are other columns you worry about you can continue the pipeline with

```
%>%
  mutate(secoes = map(...)) %>%
  unnest(secoes)
```

to flatten on secoes